# Sharepoint: Creating another view with unique values and sum

Tags: list-view, custom-list, lookup-column, calculated-column

I have such a list as per screenshot.

I need to create another view, where first column "Risk Category" will show only unique values (so only 3 items in this case: "Legal risk, "Not meet delivery expectations" and "Organizational risk").

Second column should summarize "Risk Score" values per Category (e.g. "Legal risk" - 8)

And another question. Does anyone know the formula to setup the traffic lights depending on the number range? I need "green" for <2, "yellow" 3< x <5, and "red" for > 6.

Now I'm using this validation formula depending on the selected status:

```
="<DIV><IMG src='/_layouts/images/"&IF(Status="low","kpipeppers-0",IF(OR(Status="medium"),"kpipeppers-1","kpipeppers-2"))&".gif'/></DIV>"
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

1. View: You can take a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) as to how to create view

Create a standard view and then for **Columns** select [Risk Category] and [Risk Score],
for **Group By**, select [Risk Category] and then for **Totals** select **Sum** for [Risk Score]

The output should look like this.

[image]

**2. Formula**

You can try the below and let me know.

```
=IF([Risk Score]<=2,"Green",IF(AND([Risk Score]>=3,[Risk Score]<=5),"Yellow","Red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful answer. I implemented both and it worked.

Just one question: is there a way to have a selective view without "Group by" option? I mean, without having those Group lines with sum, but having just this outcome as normal list entry?

Comment: With [All items] view without [Group By], you can see data in a table. But, when you need [Sum], this is what you would get. Only options for [Group By] available are **Collapsed** and **Expanded**. Please mark the question as answered if it provided the answer you were looking for.